# upper bound on the radius of convergence of a power series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, proof-verification, power-series

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of complex numbers. Now suppose that $\sum na_n$ converge absolutely. Prove that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ is $\geq 1$.

I don't understand where I am going wrong. 
For me it just comes from the fact that 
$$\forall z, \mid z \mid \leq 1, \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \mid a_n \mid \mid z^n \mid \leq \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \mid a_n \mid \leq \sum_{n = 0}^\infty n \mid a_n \mid$$

Hence, for all $z, \mid z \mid \leq 1$ the series $\sum a_nz^n$ converges absolutely and hence converges. So for all $z, \mid z \mid \leq 1,$ the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nz^n$ converges, thus the radius of convergence of $x \mapsto \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_nx^n$ is $1$.

Where is the problem in what I said ?

In my book they are using the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\mid a_n \mid \to 0$ to prove that the radius of convergence is $1$. So I might be wrong somewhere, since what I said is quite trivial.

Thank you!

Comment: The title is wrong. It is a lower bound, nor an upper bound.

Comment: Look up and apply the Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula,  using the fact that $|a_n|^{1/n}=\frac {|na_n|^{1/n}}{n^{1/n}}<\frac {1}{n^{1/n}}$ for all but finitely many $ n\in \Bbb Z^+.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *nothing* wrong with your approach. Actually, the problem is silly. You would be able to get the some conclusion simply assuming that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Comment: This is also what I thought. Thank you, for confirming that what I said is correct !